# XLS Read and Automatic CSV conversion

Tags: apex, javascript, csv, excel, conversion

We have a requirement to read contents (rows) from an XLS file and upload (the file as an attachment) the same once the read and insert into custom Objects are complete. My observation after investigating a while is as below:

[1] **Apex does not have the capability to read an XLS file**. But it can process CSV files.

Question:

Is there a **mechanism (libraries/custom code) where the XLS could be converted into a CSV file upon Upload**? This helps Apex to read the contents and parse?

Comment: Not sure if my previous answer on one of your other questions help. Aside from the lack of supporting password protected zip files. Apex/VF can be taught to handle XLSX files (which are zips using the Open Office format). Not sure if this helps? Unfortunately XLS files are binary, hence Microsoft switched to the newer more open format.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I did not try it yet but certainly it helps... I found an interesting post on reading Excel file...it works on a .htm page but not on VFP. 

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Read-User-Uploaded-Excel-File/td-p/111457

Comment: The binary format used by older XLS files is called the Binary Interchange File Format. It is possible to write a parser to extract the data, but it won't be a quick undertaking. I did find [JExcelApi](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi) for reading the files with Java. Converting it to Apex wouldn't be trivial. Could you create a web service to process the files?

Comment: Daniel, sounds interesting, could you pls add more details to the Web-Service approach?

Comment: I'd look into `ssconvert`