# Reading the data from .xls file and insertion

Tags: apex, excel

I have a requirement whereby customers will enter their organization contact information in .xls(excel) file which I should read and insert in to organization. Is there a way to to do that (through apex coding)?

Comment: Potential duplicate of [XLS Read and Automatic CSV conversion](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/10334/102)

Comment: It may be easier to write some macros for excel to upload the excel file to salesforce as opposed to trying to parse the data inside of salesforce. If you pick the right excel format however, I believe the excel data is in a more parser friendly xml form, which may be possible to parse in apex, but would still require you to write a complex parser.

Comment: You could also try something like allowing the file to be uploaded, and then passing that id over to a heroku service with a language which can parse the file and return the required data, but that may be too complex for your needs.